# In gcc is there any way to dynamically add a function call to the start of main()?

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic-library, ld-preload

I'm dynamically overriding `malloc()` with a `fast_malloc()` implementation of mine in a glibc benchmark malloc speed test ([`glibc/benchtests/bench-malloc-thread.c`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/benchtests/bench-malloc-thread.c)), by writing these functions in my `fast_malloc.c` file:

```
// Override malloc() and free(); see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/262481/4561887

inline void* malloc(size_t num_bytes)
{
    static bool first_call = true;
    if (first_call)
    {
        first_call = false;
        fast_malloc_error_t error = fast_malloc_init();
        assert(error == FAST_MALLOC_ERROR_OK);
    }

    return fast_malloc(num_bytes);
}

inline void free(void* ptr)
{
    fast_free(ptr);
}
```

Notice that I have this inefficient addition to my `malloc()` wrapper to ensure `fast_malloc_init()` gets called first on just the first call, to initialize some memory pools. I'd like to get rid of that and dynamically insert that init call into the start of `main()`, without modifying the glibc code, if possible. Is this possible?

The downside of how I've written my `malloc()` wrapper so far is it skews my benchtest results making it look like my `fast_malloc()` is slower than it really is, because the init func gets timed by `glibc/benchtests/bench-malloc-thread.c`, and I have this extraneous `if (first_call)` which gets checked every malloc call.

Currently I dynamically override `malloc()` and `free()`, while calling the `bench-malloc-thread` executable, like this:

```sh
LD_PRELOAD='/home/gabriel/GS/dev/fast_malloc/build/libfast_malloc.so' \ 
glibc-build/benchtests/bench-malloc-thread 1
```

Plot I will be adding my `fast_malloc()` speed tests to (using [this repo](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/malloc-benchmarks)):
[image]

LinkedIn post I made about this: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gabriel-staples_software-engineering-tradeoffs-activity-6815412255325339648-_c8L.

### Related:

1. [my repo fork] https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/malloc-benchmarks
2. [how I learned how to generate `*.so` dynamic libraries in gcc] https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html
3. [Create a wrapper function for malloc and free in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c/262481#262481)

Comment: One option is [gcc __attribute__((constructor))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html): "*The constructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters main ().*".

Comment: @kaylum, nice. That may be the answer. I'll have to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to dynamically inject function calls before and after another executable's `main()` function.

Here is a full, runnable example for anyone wanting to test this on their own. Tested on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

This code is all part of my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

[**hello_world_basic.c:**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/hello_world_basic.c)

```
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("This is the start of `main()`.\n");
    printf("  Hello world.\n");
    printf("This is the end of `main()`.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[**dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.c:**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.c)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`
#include <stdlib.h>  // For `atexit()`

/// 3. This function gets attached as a post-main() callback (a sort of program "destructor")
/// via the C <stdlib.h> `atexit()` call below
void also_called_after_main()
{
    printf("`atexit()`-registered callback functions are also called AFTER `main()`.\n");
}

/// 1. Functions with gcc function attribute, `constructor`, get automatically called **before**
/// `main()`; see:
/// https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes
__attribute__((__constructor__))
void called_before_main()
{
    printf("gcc constructors are called BEFORE `main()`.\n");

    // 3. Optional way to register a function call for AFTER main(), although
    // I prefer the simpler gcc `destructor` attribute technique below, instead.
    int retcode = atexit(also_called_after_main);
    assert(retcode == 0); // ensure the `atexit()` call to register the callback function succeeds
}

/// 2. Functions with gcc function attribute, `destructor`, get automatically called **after**
/// `main()`; see:
/// https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes
__attribute__((__destructor__))
void called_after_main()
{
    printf("gcc destructors are called AFTER `main()`.\n");
}
```

**How to build and run the dynamic `lib*.so` shared-object library and dynamically load it with `LD_PRELOAD` as you run another program** (see "[dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main__build_and_run.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main__build_and_run.sh) from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo"):

```bash
# 1. Build the other program (hello_world_basic.c) that has `main()` in it which we want to use
mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj hello_world_basic.c \
-o bin/hello_world_basic
# 2. Create a .o object file of this program, compiling with Position Independent Code (PIC); see
# here: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -fpic -c dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.c \
-o bin/dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.o
# 3. Link the above PIC object file into a dynamic shared library (`lib*.so` file); link above shows
# we must use `-shared`
gcc -shared bin/dynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.o -o \
bin/libdynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.so
# 4. Call the other program with `main()` in it, dynamically injecting this code into that other
# program via this code's .so shared object file, and via Linux's `LD_PRELOAD` trick
LD_PRELOAD='bin/libdynamic_func_call_before_and_after_main.so' bin/hello_world_basic
```

Sample output. Notice that we have injected some special function calls both **before** AND **after** the `main()` function found in "hello_world_basic.c":

> ```
> gcc constructors are called BEFORE `main()`.
> This is the start of `main()`.
>   Hello world.
> This is the end of `main()`.
> gcc destructors are called AFTER `main()`.
> `atexit()`-registered callback functions are also called AFTER `main()`.
> ```

### References:

1. How to build dynamic `lib*.so` libraries in Linux: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html
2. [@kaylum's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171246/in-gcc-is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-add-a-function-call-to-the-start-of-main#comment120485051_68171246)
3. [@Employed Russian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68171817/4561887)
4. [@Lundin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171246/in-gcc-is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-add-a-function-call-to-the-start-of-main/68219244#comment120491915_68171817)
5. gcc `constructor` and `destructor` function attributes!:
   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes
6. c `atexit()` func to register functions to be called AFTER `main()` returns or exits!:
   https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible?

Yes. You are building and `LD_PRELOAD`ing a shared library, and shared libraries can have special initializer and finalizer functions, which are called by the dynamic loader when the library is loaded and unloaded respectively.

As kaylum commented, to create such a constructor, you would use `__attribute__((constructor))`, like so:

```
__attribute__((constructor))
void fast_malloc_init_ctor()
{
  fast_malloc_error_t error = fast_malloc_init();
  assert(error == FAST_MALLOC_ERROR_OK);
}

// ... the rest of implementation here.
```

P.S.

> it skews my benchtest results making it look like my fast_malloc() is slower than it really is, because the init func gets timed

1. You are comparing with multi-threaded benchmarks. Note that your `static bool fist_call` is *not* thread-safe. In practice this will not matter, because `malloc` is normally called long before any threads (other than the main thread) exist.
2. I doubt that this single comparison *actually* makes your `fast_malloc()` slower. It probably *is* slower even after you remove the comparison -- writing a fast heap allocator takes a lot of effort, and smart people have spent many man-years optimizing GLIBC malloc, TCMalloc and jemalloc.

Comment: Similarly, `atexit` can be used to call library clean-up code if needed. It can be used from the constructor to register a callback.

Comment: @Lundin, great point. gcc also provides a `destructor` function attribute that does this too though, if one wants to stay consistent with the `constructor` style. It is described in conjunction with the `constructor` function attribute, here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes.

Comment: And for anyone looking for the `atexit()` documentation, it is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit. This is great stuff. I'm really excited to be learning about these nice features that I need to use (gcc `constructor`/`destructor` function attributes, and `atexit()`).

Comment: Regarding your P.S. bullet 2: my preliminary results indicate my **single-threaded** version of `fast_malloc()` has dropped in execution time from 17~18 clock cycles to 14~15 clock cycles simply by no longer checking the init each time and by no longer timing init when it runs the first time. So far, `fast_malloc()` is faster than all the rest. I'm anxious to see what happens when I make it multi-threaded-safe.